# Functions beeing called as different types of objects in Javascript. Is that make sense?

Tags: javascript, java, logic

Hope you're well. I'm studying Javascript after a few years without studying programming. The first thing I learned was Java and object-oriented programming. I remember the important parts like classes and methods. Studying Javascript on the Mozilla website with explanations, they say that a function is a different kind of object.

To me this doesn't make sense because an object is like something, like a cat. A function is more like a verb, an action that something or someone does, like the cat's leap. Wouldn't it be better to explain to people that functions are not objects, but actions, rather than seeing that it's an object too?

Object for me is like the subject of a sentence. Like: You work". The object/subject of the sentence is "You" and the action/verb/function is "work". We can't say, for example, "Run dances" because "Run" is a function, not an object Does that make sense, or am I just crazy? haha

Thank you friends.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster, or Car is to Carpet. They are almost entirely unrelated languages.

Comment: In JavaScript, functions are objects, even if it doesn't make sense to you. It would be technically wrong to say that functions aren't objects.

Comment: natural language analogies rarely work in programming. Even in English, you can perfectly say something like "I went for a run", and there are quite a few languages with little or no difference between verbs and nouns.

Comment: Having function available as objects is a thing that is so useful that even Java 8 kind of implemented this thing (using functional interfaces, lambda expressions and method refererences.) Simple example: you want to sort a `List<Cat>` either by weight or by age: wouldn't it be super useful if you could somehow create a generic `sort(List<Cat>, SomeComparatorFunction<Cat>)`? Actual Java has it: `java.util.Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

Comment: @BrianMoreira ... you might befriend yourself with the idea of functions as callable objects. Function objects are operated by the call operator `()` and they have methods too like `call`, `apply` and `bind`.

Answer (score 3):

Functions can *do* things, but they still **are** things. You, as a person, can do things, but you still **are** something. You can have attributes, things that describe you, while retaining your ability to take action. Functions are the same.

> Wouldn't it be better to explain to people that functions are not objects, but actions, rather than seeing that it's an object too?

In JavaScript — **and Java** — functions are actions that are also objects. In Java, you have to go through [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html); in JavaScript, it's more direct, the function is automatically an object. In Java, you have to go through reflection to get (for instance) the [parameter count](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterCount()). In JavaScript, it's just the function's [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

It's not "better" or "worse," it just **is**. Programming languages involve hundreds if not thousands of choices about how things are organized. JavaScript is organized differently from Java in a **large** number of ways. Absent personal preference, it's not generally "better" or "worse" to do X or Y, it's just *different*.

Comment: And don't forget that using functional interfaces (since Java 8) even Java has a direct (even if limited) way of treating functions as objects.

Answer (score 0):

Programming is complex and it's also unique. It's not truly *exactly* like anything else. And yet, us humans need to try to come to grips with it.

Therefore, a *lot* of programming concepts use words that already existed in the english language. We call these things 'objects'. We could have chosen to call them 'floobargles' instead, or 'bultizats' - pick a word with no inherent meaning to avoid confusion. But that also has downsides: If your first steps into learning a language involves learning 500 completely unique words first, you're going to get utterly lost.

Thus, a dilemma:

Use words with an already established meaning, such as 'object', 'method', 'function', 'actor', 'language', 'line (of code)', 'reference', 'pointer', 'instantiating' (we're teetering close to just making up entirely new words there perhaps), and so on: The meaning that these words already have helps; these aren't chosen arbitrarily, a *lot* of what an object (in the Java Language Specification sense) is and does is a lot like an object (in the 'word in the english dictionary' sense). But, inevitably, there are things where the simile falls down and in fact completely steers you wrong.

But, use newly minted words and the learning curve for those new to the language is off the scale.

Quite the dilemma.

I remember some very well meaning, but in the end completely wrong and highly misleading, post about why one should not use exceptions as control flow. The gist of it was something along the lines of:

*Using exceptions for control flow is like having bowling-lane style bumpers next to the highway and driving down the road by haphazardly bouncing between the bumpers*.

The error being made here is that the word 'exception' suggests error in the english sense of the word - a mistake, critically, *something to be avoided*. But that isn't in the language spec. Nowhere in the Java Lang Spec (or ECMAScript spec - that's the javascript equivalent of the JLS) does it say that exceptions 'should be avoided'. Quite the opposite. Also, a human would not like being jostled about while their car smashes between bumpers. Code execution isn't a human, code doesn't have feelings. It wouldn't care. There are certainly arguments one can make about using the Exception mechanism to do control flow (or rather, arguments to suggest one should *not* do that), but 'its like the bumpers on a bowling alley' is not one of them.

Correct arguments would involve performance, or an explanation about how it leads to 'spaghetti' (itself a slang term meaning: Code whose 'flow' is hard for humans to intuit). Arguments that work just as well if exceptions were called 'whutsits' instead.

### On to your dilemma specifically

In javascript, functions are assignable to variables exactly like values are. This line:

```
var x = 5;
```

is valid javascript *and also* valid java. (Using the new `var` keyword which just types the declaration to the obvious thing; it is identical to the to you probably more familiar `int x = 5;` - java is still typed, the type of the `x` variable is `int` here, in java. Javascript is still untyped, you can assign a string to `x` later in javascript, not in java).

However, this is valid javascript:

```
var x = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

... but not valid java <sup>1</sup>
and, crucially, x acts exactly the same. You can pass `x` around (you are now passing *a function* to *a function* which if we stick to the purely english meaning of the word is starting to get truly mind bogglingly weird. But step away from that - use the plasticity of the brain to blur the lines between what these words mean in english vs. what they mean in the lang spec, and it's really not that hard to understand the idea of passing functions around to other functions). You can ask x what kind of object it is (and it will say: I am a function).

In other words, `x` is now pointing at a function... *which is also an object*. Like in physics, light is both a wave and a particle, and also is neither (there are ways in which light is NOT like waves at all, and ways in which light is NOT like particles at all) - and so are functions in javascript. They are like objects in some ways, and not like them in other ways.

The real problem is simply communication. The book / tutorial / person who is telling you "functions are like objects" is *actually* trying to convey something that takes way more words to say. For example, their *intent* is to communicate the idea: "Functions in javascript can be written anywhere values can be, and can be stored in the same places values can be, and they even *are* a dictionary (see below), and can be passed around just like values can be".

In *their head*, 'Functions are objects' *exactly* covers this, and thus to them it's simply an easier way to say the same thing.

So, their brain tells their mouth to make sounds, your ears hear these sounds and your brain... comes to a *completely different conclusion*.

That's simply failure of communication: Words were said, you understood the basic meaning (you didn't mishear them), and yet the point of using your words is to communicate and that emphatically did not happen here. They MEANT one thing, and you UNDERSTOOD a different thing.

It happens, all the time, in all sorts of different contexts. Programming is by no means unique in this.

The upshot is: So what, right? If you think 'functions are like objects' is not correct at all, that doesn't mean that you are wrong, or that the person who says 'functions ARE like objects' are wrong. It might merely mean that you have a pretty fundamental different idea about what these words mean. There generally is no dictator that decides what a given word is to mean, and who will decree anyone is to be killed who fails to use the word in precisely the determined fashion.

The one place you get into trouble is, again, communication. If everybody else on the entire planet conjures up X idea when they hear the word 'object', and you are the only one who conjures up opposite idea Y, then you live in your own little world, which is a bad thing: Programming is a team effort. Even if you write your code on your own, you read tutorials, books, use libraries, write documentation, and so on. It is *inevitable* that shorthand, jargon, and slang drips into docs, and if you just aren't thinking of the same thing everybody else is thinking of, your docs are unreadable to others, and you are not capable of reading docs written by others.

And therein lies a complication: Even though there is no dictatorial source of the true meaning of every bit of jargon, the opposite (everybody just gets to pick what they feel any bit of jargon means, it's all equally valid) leads to chaos. Everybody needs to make their own call on this.

However, certain words are used and specifically defined in official specifications, or are above 99% agreement amongst all programmers in the entire community. Clearly for those words, it's best to just jump on the bandwagon.

And 'object', for javascript, might be one of them. In javascript, objects have properties you can set and read:

```
var x = {};
x["hello"] = "goodbye";
console.log(x.hello); // prints 'goodbye'.
x(); // fails; x is not a function.
```

Weirdly enough you can do that to functions:

```
var x = function() {};
x["hello"] = "goodbye";
console.log(x.hello); // works
x(); // works fine - x is a function that does nothing.
console.log(x.hello); // still works, prints 'goodbye'.
```

Hence, 'functions are also objects'. Yes, at this point the english underlying meaning of these words is starting to, if anything, be confusing. How can a thing be a verb but also be, more or less, a noun? In english, that's a stupid idea.

In javascript, well, that's just how it is. Whatever words or similes you need to conjure up so that your brain easily intuits the way of things (that is, you read some javascript code and correctly understand what it does nearly instantly), do that. Most people think saying 'functions are objects' is how to get there. But maybe for you that's just confusing. That's fine.

[1] Something like `Runnable r = () -> {};` *is* valid java, but something quite different is going on there: That function definition (`() -> {}` - no arguments in, do nothing out) is being treated as an instance of a newly minted, anonymously named class that subtypes Runnable, and has an implementation of its only `abstract` method: `void run();`, and that function is it.

Comment: A wonderful explanation. Thanks. It made me smile while reading. What an interesting world of coding. Thanks. I will think of everything you just answered.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it doesn't make much sense, but that's how it's made in JavaScript

Example:

```js
// create a function
function run() {
  console.log('run')
}

// calls a function
run()

// adds a property to a function like to an object
run.x = 5
console.log(run.x)

// adds a functions to the function

run.another = () => console.log('another function')
run.another()

// checks if the functions is an instance of Object
console.log(run instanceof Object)
```

Comment: Does it man I can add properties to functions without even creating the property inside of the function? Like, I don't need to add inside of run() the "x" property, I just have to call it with the "run" object and add  a value? That's really nice.

Comment: Because I remember, in Java, you must create all the functions of a object inside of the object itself. But this way JS does, makes things even faster.

Comment: JavaScript 's objects are more like hash maps , you can add anything at any time. You don't have to declare a class to make an object